# Make variables available in the whole view (including @yields) using View composers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to have a $user variable available each time the "views/layouts/master.blade.php" view is called, so this is basically my current approach:

**app/controllers/BaseController.php**

```
class BaseController extends Controller{

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';    

    protected function setupLayout(){
        if(!is_null($this->layout)){
            $this->layout = \View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

    protected function view($path, $data = []){
        return $this->layout->content = \View::make($path, $data);
    }

}
```

**app/controllers/DashboardController.php**

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController{

    public function index(){

        return $this->view('dashboard');

    }

}
```

**App\Composers\BaseComposer.php**

```
class BaseComposer{
    public function compose($view){

        $data = array(
            'user' => \Auth::user()
        );

        $view->with($data);

    }
}
```

**app/composers.php**

```
View::composer('layouts.master', 'App\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

**app/views/layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <button>{{{ $user->name }}}</button> //Button with the user name with a dropdown to log out (I'm using the $user variable from the composer)
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app/views/dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master') //Should I put this eventhough I'm using controller templating? ($layout->content =  View::make(...))

@section('content')
    <p class="welcome">Welcome, {{{ $user->name }}}</p>
@stop
```

When I hit the index() method I'm getting a **Undefined variable: user** Exception in my dashboard.blade.php view.

As you can see I'm using my BaseController to provide some view helper methods such as "setUpLayout" and "view" and both of them are running View::make(). So eventhough I use my composer to call "with()" in my "layouts.master" view, the "dashboard" view will not be inheriting those variables. I took a look at the source code and Illuminate\View\View::with() doesn't do much more than append data to a $data property, so it seems each View::make() call is independent from one another.

So here's the problem: How can I define in just one call all the variables I need for a view and its "@yields"?

I've been researching and some people suggest to define the composer like this:

```
View::composer('*', 'App\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

And that will work but the View composer will be executed for every single view. So imagine if my View composer has a DB call that questy will be executed as many times as views I have, including views like my "views/emails" folder where I don't need to call the composer...

I've been thinking on start defining my view variables in a property in my BaseController and since I'm extending it in my DashboardController I could do something like:

```
View::make('dashboard')->with($this->data);
```

But I like the idea of having View composers, they're just not working as I'm expecting... maybe I'm doing it wrong, so I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `View::share()` instead of `with`

```
class BaseComposer{
    public function compose($view){

        $data = array(
            'user' => \Auth::user()
        );

        View::share($data);
    }
}
```

Regarding your comment in dashboard.blade.php, you don't need the `@extends` if you always set the layout in your controller and it is best practice to only define the layout in one place.

Comment: I think that's `View::share` :)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not passed along to yielded sections, so that's why the view that extends the layout doesn't get the variable. However you don't need to use wildcards in the composer to attach the variable to every view, you can specify an array of views you want the composer to be attached to. In your case it's the layout view and dashboard view:

```
View::composer(array('layouts.master', 'dashboard'), 'App\Composers\BaseComposer');
```

You can add any other views that need the `$user` variable, to that array. For more info you can check the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers).

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this, besides having to manually define each view to compose, is that the composer will be executed twice and that could cause some troubles specially if you're making DB queries from them. However, I find this really useful when defining multiple views that are not going to be rendered together.